# Service vs Listener in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm new to oracle environment. I want to know the difference between service and listener in oracle?

I'm just doing my assignment on accessing an oracle database over a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Oracle Net Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/application-and-networking-architecture.html#GUID-D6E2465E-E8E6-4B95-95D3-B9581E264ED1)

> The Oracle Net Listener (the listener) is a server-side process that
>   listens for incoming client connection requests and manages traffic to
>   the database.

[Service Names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/application-and-networking-architecture.html#GUID-C931A159-E1FE-4DB3-A811-510C42516683)

> A service name is a logical representation of a service used for
>   client connections.
>
> When a client connects to a listener, it requests a connection to a
>   service. When a database instance starts, it registers itself with a
>   listener as providing one or more services by name. Thus, the listener
>   acts as a mediator between the client and instances and routes the
>   connection request to the right place.
>
> A single service, as known by a listener, can identify one or more
>   database instances. Also, a single database instance can register one
>   or more services with a listener. Clients connecting to a service need
>   not specify which instance they require.

Comment: gave you a very good and accurate technical description.  Here's a non-technical explanation:  The listener is your company's switchboard operator.  The service(s) is the name(s) of the people to whom the switchboard operator can connect you to.